# Karma startup and teardown config

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

When running Karma tests, I would like to start HTTP server to do some cross-origin network requests in tests. Is there a natural way to start the server before Karma tests start and close the server when Karma exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `new karma.Server()`:

```
// @ts-check
const karma = require('karma');
const path = require('path');
const {createEchoServer} = require('./echo-server');

async function run() {
    const configPath = path.join(__dirname, './karma.conf.js');
    const karmaConfig = karma.config.parseConfig(configPath, {});

    const echoServer = await createEchoServer();
    const karmaServer = new karma.Server(karmaConfig, () => {
        echoServer.close();
    });
    karmaServer.start();
}

run();
```